# Interpretation of Soilgrid attributes

Tags: soilgrids, soil

I am interested in obtaining data on soil classification from the soil grid website https://www.soilgrids.org/. I could download the data but did not find clearly how to interpret the attributes of the downloaded TIFF files. The values range from 0 to 29 (at least in the study area of concern).

This is an example of one of the tiff files:
[image: This is an example of one of the tiff files]

Could you please explain to me what these values represent and which value should be considered NA?

I assume it would be value 0, but I want to double check this.

---

**EDIT 1**

Here is a reproducible R script for loading a sample data

```
require(raster)
require(dplyr)

TmpFile <- tempfile()
download.file("https://maps.isric.org/mapserv?map=/map/wrb.map&SERVICE=WCS&VERSION=2.0.1&REQUEST=GetCoverage&COVERAGEID=MostProbable&FORMAT=image/tiff&SUBSET=long(26.0725,28.0725)&SUBSET=lat(59.0279,61.0279)&SUBSETTINGCRS=http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/EPSG/0/4326&OUTPUTCRS=http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/EPSG/0/4326", TmpFile, mode = "wb")

R <- raster::raster(TmpFile)
R[] %>% table()
# 0      1      6     12     14     16     18     20     23 
# 466005  14719 145254  65501      1   7417  29757      3 192943 

plot(R)
```

[image]

---

**EDIT 2**

The challenge is how to separate the value of zero from NA values. The map below does not tell the difference between zero and NA. Replacing 0 with NA does not solve this issue

[image]

Anyway, I found a better solution. Downloading the data from this [link](https://files.isric.org/soilgrids/latest/data/wrb) solved my issue, as it distinguish clearly zeros from NA values.

---

Comment: Have you checked with the FAQ and maybe gotten into contact with the data provider?

Comment: Thanks Erik for your comment. This info is not clear for me in the website's FAQ. The website recommends to ask questions related to soilgrids here in stackexchange..

Comment: Which layer/data did you download.  What do you mean by NA in this case; no value/not measured or something else?

Comment: I updated the question and added a reproducible R script.  The data represent soil classification. There is data values in seas/oceans, which should be assigned with NA value. More important for me now is to understand the meaning of the values. Thanks

Comment: After you last edit this post now includes different questions. GIS.SE does not function that way, it is not a forum or mail-list. Please take some time to pore through the [Tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

As @Erik suggested, this information is detailed in the [FAQ](https://www.isric.org/explore/soilgrids/faq-soilgrids#What_happened_to_the_maps_of_soil_types):

> An additional, ‘summary’ map provides for each cell the RSG’s with highest probability of occurrence. It is called Most Probable and was obtained by selecting the RSG with the highest probability of occurrence for each map cell from the aggregated RSG probability maps described above. The RAT (Raster Attribute Table) with the legend of the classes is available in the VRT file and [here](https://files.isric.org/soilgrids/latest/data/wrb/MostProbable.rat.xml).

Comment: Thanks Luis. The challenge, as I explained in the edited question, was the use of zero both for Acrisols and NA. Data from the same source (through a different link) solved my issue as it discriminates between zeros and NA. Cheers.